# How to use User Defined Attribute in D language?

Tags: annotations, d

According to the [doc](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#uda), I have this program:

```
void main() {
    @(3)
    int var;
}
```

But it just doesn't compile:

```
test.d(2): identifier expected after @, not (
test.d(2): basic type expected, not 3
test.d(2): no identifier for declarator int
test.d(2): semicolon expected, not '3'
test.d(2): found ')' when expecting ';' following statement
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature was added a few releases ago. So check your compiler version and see if you need an update. The latest release is v2.064.2.

If you're using dmd run `dmd -v`.
If you're using ldc2 run `ldc2 -version`.
GDC would have a similar way too.